# How I can wait until the value get updated then I use it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    //....
) {

    constructor(
        userID: Int
    ) : this(
        userID,
        //...
    )
}
```

Dao class

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    fun addUser(user: User): Long
    
    //.......
}
```

Repository Class

```
class RoomUserRepository(context: Context) {
    //...
    suspend fun addUser(user: User): Long = userDao.addUser(user)
    //...
}
```

ViewMode Class

```
class UserViewModel(val context: Application) : AndroidViewModel(context) {
    //...

    var userID: Long = 0

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userID = roomUserRepository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

SIGN UP Button `onclick{}`

```
clicked = !clicked
if (confirmpassword != password) {
    message = "Incorrect password! please try again"
} else if (inputChack(fullname, email, password)) {
    message = "Information is incomplete"
} else {
    // Create User
    user.email = email
    user.fullName = fullname
    user.password = password
    userVM.addUser(user)
    // Create Cart
    cart.userID = userVM.userID.toInt()
    cartVM.addCart(cart)
    Log.d("user & cart", "adding users & cart")
}
```

As you can see when the user click on `SIGN UP` I will Create `User & Cart` in my database, user creation  work fine but when I create cart I have to pass user ID and I am getting it from `userID` variable you can find it in `ViewMode Class` the problem is  the value is getting `cart.userID = userVM.userID.toInt()` then it been updated

Simply I want 
After called `userVM.addUser(user)` I have to wait until the `userID` variable get updated (look at ViewMode Class) then I get the updated value `cart.userID = userVM.userID.toInt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this:

```
 fun addUser(user: User, callBack: (Long) -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userID = roomUserRepository.addUser(user)
            callBack(userID)
        }
    }

// Create User
user.email = email
user.fullName = fullname
user.password = password
userVM.addUser(user) { id ->
    cart.userID = id
        cartVM.addCart(cart)
        Log.d("user & cart", "adding users & cart")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert),
the return value of the below function is the rowId, not the userID.

```
@Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
fun addUser(user: User): Long
```

If you want to get the userID, you should write a get function like below.

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table)
   fun getUsers(): Flow<List<User>>
```

Then, add an observer like below

```
   val users = roomUserRepository.getUsers().asLiveData()
```

Also don't forget to add the necessary dependencies.

```
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Actually user id = row id

Comment: and my problem is the userID variable get updated after it create cart

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to read the userId before coroutine scope finishes it job. Try my second answer